# How can I change an attribute of an object using something the user has entered?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I know about using `print(object, attribute_choice))` to print an attribute but is there a similar possibility to change it? `attribute_choice` is enterd by the user.

Comment: Please note that it can be a huge security risk to evaluate user input as python code. Even if it's just access to an attribute - it could for example be a property and run code.

Comment: I don't know your use-case but it sounds like you might want to use a dictionary instead. Only one reason is because there are no property-like values in dictionaries that get executed automatically when accessing a specific key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setattr(obj, "myattr", "new_value")`.